# Insert into Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

```
insert into tablex (a,b,c)
select distinct a,b,c
from tableA;
```

when I run select distinct statement alone it shows 6 rows.
When I run with insert it shows 0 rows inserted .

Is it a bug or AM I missing some thing.

```
#Teradata 13.10
```

masked original  Query

```
INSERT INTO tablex
  (SYSTEM_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,CURRENT_FLAG )                
SELECT DISTINCT                     
    ,s.SYSTEM_ID                     
    ,s.trans_DATE
    ,DATE '9999-12-31' 
    ,'X' 
FROM  s JOIN  cc
ON s.var_id=cc.var_id
WHERE s.sno = cc.sno
AND s.sno<>s.orino AND s.orino IS NOT NULL AND s.orino <> ''
AND cc.end_date=s.trans_date-1;
```

Comment: What does `select count(*) from tablex` return? Also what client do you use and what transaction mode you're using (Ansi or Teradata)?

Comment: If it's a,b,c and a,b,c, wouldn't you get ambiguous column error?  Perhaps show us the real query, or something closer to it.

Comment: @jboi Teradata Mode , count(*) from table x = 220,955

Comment: Is that 6 more then it was before the inser?

Comment: @jboi it was before insert . My insert was processing 0 rows . so same count. before and after . Client was SQL assistant 13.10.0.09

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug :-)

All six rows existed already in the target table and it's a SET table which automatically removes duplicate rows during an Insert/Select.

Comment: Dieter was faster :-) If you want to have the six rows inserted, create the table as `multiset`.

Comment: i figured out . Thank you